# UITableView Cell issue - off screen cells are not shown when scrolled

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, swift3, xcode8

Only those cell are displaying which are fitting on screen. if scrolled to next(offscreen) cell only white screen is displayed. it allows to scroll but only white space is displayed. Even the last row which was half displayed is also remains half only.

```
extension LiveTVController: UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {


func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let reuseIdentifier = tableView.tag == 1 ? ProgrammeListCell.reuseIdentifier : StreamListCell.reuseIdentifier
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)

    if let cell = cell as? StreamListCell {
        cell.programmeList.delegate = self
        cell.programmeList.dataSource = self
    }

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return tableView.tag == 2 ? 10 : 0
}
```

[image: On Screen launch]

Now after scrolled down for next rows. there are total 10 sections returned and each section have 1 row.

[image: After scrolling to down]

Comment: Is the table view present inside a scroll view? Is a scroll view present inside the cell? Are there are gesture recognizers present in the view? Looking at your UI it seems that you have swipe left / right to navigate between screens, Please confirm.

Comment: @ Windindi I have tableView on main view and collection view in tableview cell.

Comment: Why does your tableView 10 sections? And only 1 record per section?

Comment: i want to have some space between two rows so instead of creating 10 rows i have created 10 sections with 1 row for each section and returning footer view to each section with height 10 pt.  given values are hardcoded. to test the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the height of cell according to cell type.And also place this video view in a table view header instead of using cell for first element.

Comment: video view is outside of table view., will try specifing height. it is fixed for all rows.

Comment: is it fixed or not ?

Comment: @DattatrayDeokar if its help please upvote I am new user I need to unlock facilities